# Spring-boot Configuring properties with dash/hyphen using environment variables

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, environment-variables

One of my favorite spring-boot feature is the ability to configure most things using the unix environment variables.
Now I'm struggling with ActiveMQ broker config.

To set the broker url I have to specify **spring.activemq.broker-url**.
Rewritten in envrionment terms this would be **SPRING_ACTIVEMQ_BROKER-URL** which is working from eclipse, but not possible to be defined as environment variable in any unix shell.

using *env* is due to other restrictions not an option

Is there something I missed or do I have to remap those "dashed" properties in an own @PropertiesConfiguration

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding).

The key in your `application.properties` or `application.yml` file will be `spring.activemq.broker-url` and your env var will be `SPRING_ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: Both will work though (tested with latest spring boot)
SPRING_ACTIVEMQ_BROKER-URL or
SPRING_ACTIVEMQ_BROKER_URL

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23659/can-shell-variable-name-include-a-hyphen-or-dash